# Cout change the variable value

Tags: c++

In the main function,if i call the `cout << answer << "\n";`,
the final answer will be change.Can someone explain to me why this happen ?

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

int Even(int *num){

    return (*num)/2;
}


int Odd(int *num){

    return 3*(*num)+1;
}

int Cycle (int num){
        int cycle;

        while (num != 1){

        if( num%2 == 0 ){  

            num= Even(&num) ;

        }else{

            num = Odd(&num) ;
        }

        cycle++;
    }
        return  cycle+1 ;
}



int main(){

    int num1,num2,max=0,answer;

    cin>>num1;
    cin>>num2;

    for(int i = (num1 < num2 ?  num1 : num2) ; i<=num2 ; i++ ){

        answer = Cycle(i);

//Here is the PROBLEM
        cout << answer << "\n";

        if(max < answer){
            max = answer;
        }

    }

    cout <<"Final Answer "<< max <<"\n" ;

  return 0;
}
```

Input 1 10

Output without cout Final Answer 68
Output with cout Final Answer 20

Comment: Use `std::cout << n << std::endl;` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: @Mayerz, The output is flushed when `std::cout` is destroyed. That doesn't explain the final answer *changing*, either.

Comment: I just misread, thoguth he deleted an immportant line but no

Comment: Which input values did you use for `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: By the way, there are `std::max` and `std::min` functions.

Comment: ya,my main focus is why the Final Answer change after the cout ?.Any thought guys ?

Comment: You need to define initial value of `cycle` variable in `Cycle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `cout`.

First, your `Odd` and `Even` functions should not take pointers, as you are returning the value already.

Second, you're not initializing the variable `cycle` in the `Cycle` function.

This code runs correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Even(int num){

    return (num)/2;
}


int Odd(int num){

    return (3*(num)+1);
}

int Cycle (int num){
    int cycle = 0;

    while (num != 1){

        if( num%2 == 0 ){

            num= Even(num) ;

        }else{

            num = Odd(num) ;
        }

        cycle++;
    }
    return  (cycle+1) ;
}



int main(){

    int num1,num2, max=0, answer;
    cin>>num1;
    cin>>num2;
    for(int i = (num1 < num2 ?  num1 : num2) ; i<=num2 ; i++ ){

        answer = Cycle(i);

        if(max < answer){
            max = answer;
        }

    }

    cout <<"Final Answer "<< max <<"\n" ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx man,actually,i still trying to understand the idea of pointer. Thx for your answer.I should initialize the cycle variable.

Comment: In ```C++``` it is more common to use references for the cases you actually want to modify the value of a variable. I recommend [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) page, it explains it quite well.